# Calling This and function arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I have these two functions:

```
function item_button_avail_click (button, item_modal) {
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
    showModal(item_modal)})
}

function showModal(item_modal_id) {
    let modal= document.getElementById(item_modal_id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

In my HTML file, I have this button:

```
<div id="item-modal" class="item-modal">
  <p>Shown On Click</p>
</div>

<button id="test-button"
        class="test-button"
        onclick="item_button_avail_click('this','item-modal')">
        Click To Show Modal
</button>
```

and the css:

```
.item-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

The intention is to display the `item-modal` when the button is clicked.
In function `item_button_avail_click`, since I pass the first argument as `button`, if I do this:

```
function item_button_avail_click (button, item_modal) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    showModal(item_modal)})
}
```

the code does not work. If I used `this.addEventListener` instead, the the whole code works as intended.

My question is: why doesn't calling `button` argument work?

Comment: `'this'` is a string with 4 characters, not a button

Comment: @CertainPerformance When passing ```'this'``` to ```button``` argument, do you mean that I am not passing the DOM element button? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Would you expect `'this'.addEventListener` to work? If not, why would it work when you pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @GuyIncognito I see. Ok, I tried ```onclick="item_button_avail_click(this,'item-modal')"```, without the quotes and it works. Thanks. I thought the convention of passing an element is to use the quotes.

Comment: That would be correct if you were passing an element ID, and the function then called `document.getElementById()`. It's not correct when passing the element itself.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for explaining. Newbie to JavaScript here.

Comment: You're assigning an event handler to the button onclick.  You want to do that when the page loads instead.

Comment: @James Do you mean I am doing double ```click``` event listening here? So the first ```listening``` should be ```onload``` on whatever element containing the button instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a "data-modal" attribute to each button so it knows the id of the modal it operates.  Then you just add an event listener to each button that makes it call showModal with the "data-modal" attribute as the parameter.

```js
function showModal(item_modal_id) {
    let modal= document.getElementById(item_modal_id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// get all buttons with class = 'test-button'
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".test-button");

// add an event listener to each button
// this could be another function that calls showModal, but here
// I just "bind" the showModal function to the appropriate modal id

[...buttons].forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', showModal.bind(null, btn.dataset.modal));
});
```

```css
.item-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="item-modal" class="item-modal">
  <p>Shown On Click</p>
</div>
<button class="test-button" data-modal="item-modal">
  Click To Show Modal
</button>

<br>

<div id="item-modal2" class="item-modal">
  <p>Shown On Click 2</p>
</div>
<button class="test-button" data-modal="item-modal2">
  Another Modal
</button>
```